# How to remove a frequency range from an audio file using SoX command?

Tags: sox

I want to remove a certain frequency range from an audio file which is uploaded to the server. I learnt that SoX command has such capabilities.

I couldn't find the exact way to accomplish this. Any help is most welcome.

Answer (score 5):

The command you are looking for could be sinc.

As an example: to remove the 5k-10k range from a wave file, 
try

```
sox input.wav output.wav sinc 10k-5k
```

You might want to read the manual about the other parameter sinc offers to get the best qulaity result for your task.

Comment: I suppose sinc option is replaced with filter. Source: man sox

Comment: I tested the command (with sox for windows 14.3.1) and it worked as requested.

Comment: Using sox 12.18.1 on centos 5.5. Then may be sinc is a later addition. Good to know! Thanks for pointing out and as it will be documented here.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the bandreject filter in `sox`.  Something like:

```
sox -V your.wav out.wav bandreject 1600 20
```

Comment: just tried the same command.. Checked the resulting file's spectral view in Adobe Soundbooth, no change at all. Its identical to the original wav file.